# Apache ProxyPass to Jboss on other machine

Tags: apache, apache2, jboss5.x, mod-proxy

I have apache server and a JBoss server on different machine. I'd like to redirect traffic for mydomain.com to JBoss 192.168.1.100:8080. .

Below is the configuration

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyRequests Off
ServerName mydomain.com
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all

</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.100:8080/  
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.100:8080/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /

</VirtualHost>
```

When i access the domain am getting "Service Temporarily Unavailable". If i configure the jboss on same machine i can access

Kindly suggest how to access jobss on different machine

Answer (score 0):

You may need to allow JBoss to bind to other addresses than localhost.  Edit your standalone.xml file and in the public interface to be the following

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```